# How to return nothing from lambda in Kotlin on Android? (Type mismatch)

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

So I got this function in Kotlin:

```
 private fun initComponents(){
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listView)

        lv?.setOnItemLongClickListener { _, _, i, _ ->
            removeItem(i) <- Error Here
        }
    }

fun removeItem(index : Int){
        items.removeAt(index) 
    }
```

where items is an ArrayList.

And it gives me an error in the lambda -

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Boolean
> Found:
> Unit

I'm new to Kotlin.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a `Boolean` value to indicate if you consumed the event or not:

```kotlin
        lv?.setOnItemLongClickListener { _, _, i, _ ->
            removeItem(i)
            true
        }
```

Comment: cool that works, but how come the - setOnItemClickListener doesn't require that?

Comment: @NadavHoltzman: `setOnClickListener()` takes an `OnClickListener`. Its `onClick()` method returns `void`, which maps to `Unit` in Kotlin. `setOnLongClickListener()` takes an `OnLongClickListener`. Its `onLongClick()` method returns `boolean`.